# how to build a svn-client library for node.js

Tags: svn, node.js

I would like to build a subversion client library for node.js.

First, do you know if this already exists ?

If not, do your have any insight for such an endeavor ? should I

- code the whole client protocol in javascript ?
- wrap a native library (which one?) as a node.js plugin ?
- wrap command line calls in a node.js module ?

Do you know of an elegant subversion client API in another language that i could "clone" ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The roadmap is silent on anything with node.js http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html so you might be the first. Do the wrap command line first, that gets you going, then the native library (svn client sources are available so you compile it your self) to learn the quirks of node.js and finally port the native library to node.js.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very robust svn client library in C, available today as a part of the subversion project.  It is wrapped with SWIG with provided bindings for Perl, Python, and Ruby.  You can see the [status of the official bindings](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL) in the official Subversion repository.  I believe that Python actually has the best supported non-C bindings, so if you wanted to look at a robust implementation, I'd start there.

I know other people have finished the SWIG->language extensions themselves, such as the PHP [SVN PECL library](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn).

In terms of what approach I'd take - if you had to, as an interim step, wrap command line calls in node.js.  But I think you are going to want to wrap the native C library, either directly or via the SWIG bindings.  That is going to give you the best performance and the best compatibility.